# How to extract artist's name from plain text?

Tags: text, nlp

I'm new to NLP.
I want to extract music artist's name from plain text like that is posted on social media.

The text looks like this. (this is just sample, not real)

> Today bandcamp is waiving fees again! CHANGE, TAYLOR SWIFT and POP
>   SMOKE will be using all funds collected through bandcamp to donate to
>   Anti Repression Committee. No Justice No Peace.

This time,I want to extract string "CHANGE","TAYLOR SWIFT","POP SMOKE".
I already tried NLTK and spaCy but it didn't work as desired.

Is there any other idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a list of artists to start with. With general words like "Change" it is very difficult. Also, there is an artist called "No Justice", which you would probably match in your example as well, even though they are not mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for comment.I'll have artist list.Yes,I know It's so hard to extract "CHANGE".It's also hard not to extract "NO JUSTICE".So I need some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of upper case data like in your example, you might want to pass the data through a truecaser first. There’s one available in the Stanford NLP package. After that, spacy might have a better shot at picking the names out. On this text:

```
Today bandcamp is waiving fees again! Change, Taylor Swift, and Pop Smoke will be using all funds collected through bandcamp to donate to Anti Repression Committee. No Justice No Peace.
```

en_core_web_sm will pick out Taylor Swift and Pop Smoke as entities. Change / CHANGE is going to be tough for any model to pick out.

Comment: Thank you for comment.I'll get plain text from social media.So It's possible that artist's name is upper case or lower case,sometime mixed.I checked spaCy could extract Taylor Swift and Pop Smoke.I'll check how to train model of spaCy.